# C++ generate function with template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

How can I generate a function using template metaprogramming. What I want to do is have a bunch of functions that basically do the same thing:

```cpp
Type1 fun1(int arg1, int arg2) {
  Type1 newType1 = {};
  newType1.arg1 = arg1;
  newType1.arg2 = arg2;

  return newType1;
}

Type2 fun2(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, bool arg4) {
  Type2 newType2 = {};
  newType2.arg1 = arg1;
  newType2.arg2 = arg2;
  newType2.arg3 = arg3;
  newType2.arg4 = arg4;

  return newType2;
}
```

So basically I don't want to write all these functions myself, I want for example say that I want a function `fun1` that takes two int arguments and assign them to a new object of Type1 using templates but how?

My idea is to have a template function that takes a type (here Type1 or Type2) and pointers-to-members of these types, so the only thing I have to do is give the template the pointers-to-members and it generates the function that takes arguments of the corresponding type.

Comment: I personally would give `Type1` and `Type2` the appropriate constructors (or make sure they are aggregates).  This would let you make a variadic function that just forwards all of the arguments to the constructor.  And it may simplify your code enough to avoid needing these functions in the first place!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) answer:

```
template<auto PMem>
struct member_type {};
template<class T, class M, M(T::*ptr)>
struct member_type<ptr> { using type=M; };
template<auto PMem>
using member_type_t=typename member_type<PMem>::type;

template<class T, auto...PMem>
T func( member_type_t<PMem>... args ) {
  T retval = {};
  ( ((retval.*PMem) = std::forward<member_type_t<PMem>>(args)), ... );
  return retval;
}
```

test code:

```
struct Bob {
  int x,y;
};

int main() {
    Bob b = func<Bob, &Bob::x, &Bob::y>( 2, 3 );
    (void)b;
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96b654c0b386ff54).

You can also perfect forward without matching types.  This has the downside that this doesn't work:

```
struct A {
  int x, y;
};
struct B {
  A one, two;
};
B func<B, &B::one, &B::two>( {1,2}, {3,4} );
```

but it does eliminate some boilerplate above, and it could remove a redundant move per member field.

To do that, simply drop the `member_type` helper completely:

```
template<class T, auto...PMem, class...Args>
T func( Args&&... args ) {
  T retval = {};
  ( ((retval.*PMem) = std::forward<Args>(args)), ... );
  return retval;
}
```

Doing this outside of [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) is a pain.  You lack `auto` parameters and `...` expansion of statements.  The second is relatively easy to work around with some boilerplate, but the first makes your desired syntax basically impossible; you may be reduced to using macros.

If you don't want `<>` syntax:

```
template<class T, auto...PMem>
constexpr auto make_func() {
  return +[]( member_type_t<PMem>... args )->T {
    T retval = {};
    ( ((retval.*PMem) = std::forward<member_type_t<PMem>>(args)), ... );
    return retval;
  };
}

struct Bob {
  int x,y;
};

constexpr auto* func = make_func<Bob, &Bob::x, &Bob::y>();
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1eb7f4e07ef6c724).

A constexpr function pointer should be treated nearly indistinguishably from a function, except overloading isn't available.

In MSVC you might have to disambiguate the function pointer type like this:

```
template<class T, auto...PMem>
using func_t = T(*)(member_type_t<PMem>...);

template<class T, auto...PMem>
constexpr func_t<T, PMem...> make_func() {
  return []( member_type_t<PMem>... args )->T {
    T retval = {};
    ( ((retval.*PMem) = std::forward<member_type_t<PMem>>(args)), ... );
    return retval;
  };
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6814aa865aa985e2).

**Sometimes** MSVC has problems with unary operator `+` on stateless lambdas having multiple different calling convention optoins.  The above avoids that issue, at the cost of a bit of boilerplate.

Comment: You can use `...` to expand a pack of values and a pack of types in one go..? :O I've never been this surprised for like 2 years regarding C++ quircks...

Comment: Thank you, but now how can I for example generate a function `foo` that is in fact `func<Bob, &Bob::x, &Bob::y>` so I can directly call `foo(1, 2)` for example?

Comment: @Kiosto I belive you would need static reflection for that (to know, for example, how many fields does your type have), which is currently not supported in any C++ standard.

Comment: @Kiosto Do you mind if it is a static object or constexpr function pointer instead of an actual function?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I don't know, what is the difference? As long as I can call it like an actual function it's fine

Comment: @Kiosto Added. Note that overloading cannot be available; the name must be unique (in its namespace).